# Pass paramenters to custom class in .NET Core API

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I got a custom mail class and I want to pass email configurations extracted from appSettings.json to the custom Mail class from the startup class. How can I achieve this?

```
  public class Mail
  {        
        private IOptions<ApplicationSettings> _applicationSettings;

        public Mail(ApplicationSettings applicationSettings)
        {
            _applicationSettings = applicationSettings;

        }
   }

public class Startup
{

   services.Configure<ApplicationSettings> 
   (Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));

}
```

Comment: Don't you need to inject `IOptions<ApplicationSettings>` in the constructor instead of just `ApplicationSettings`? Also have you ensured that the `Configuration.GetSection` is correct and returns the correct values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this is how I have setup my Email Configuration in my project. This code is for your sample reference and I really hope it helps you out.

The `appsettings.json` is as follows:

```
  "EmailConfiguration": 
  {
    "Host": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 587,
    "MailAddress": "youremailaddress@example.com",
    "MailDisplayName": "Your Display Name",
    "Username": "youremailaddress@example.com",
    "Password": "yourpassword"
  }
```

The `EmailConfiguration` class which is basically a model to hold your settings from the config file will look like:

```
public class EmailConfiguration
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string MailAddress { get; set; }
    public string MailDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The`interface` in which you would declare your generic `SendEmail` method will look like:

```
public interface IEmailManager
{
   bool SendEmail<T>(string subject, string body, string fromAddress, List<string> toAddresses, List<string> ccAddresses, List<string> bccAddresses, string name = "", List<string> filePaths = null, string htmlFile = "", T data = default(T), bool apptUpdate=false);
}
```

And finally the class that will implement the above interface will look like:

```
public class EmailManager : IEmailManager
{
    private readonly EmailConfiguration _emailSettings;

    public EmailManager(EmailConfiguration emailConfiguration)
    {
        _emailSettings = emailConfiguration;
    }

    public bool SendEmail<T>(string subject, string body, string fromAddress, List<string> toAddresses, List<string> ccAddresses, List<string> bccAddresses, string name = "", List<string> filePaths = null, string htmlFile = "", T data = default(T), bool apptUpdate = false)
    {
           string host = _emailSettings.Host;
           SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(_emailSettings.Host, _emailSettings.Port);
           smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
           smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
           MailAddress from = new MailAddress(_emailSettings.MailAddress, _emailSettings.MailDisplayName);
           smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_emailSettings.Username, _emailSettings.Password);
           MailMessage myMail = new MailMessage();
           myMail.From = from;

          //Rest logic to send email
    }    
}
```

Make sure your register the class in your `Startup.cs` under the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
var emailSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration");
services.Configure<EmailConfiguration>(emailSettingsSection);
```

This method can be used for your other config settings also.